# 98 Volvo S70 Manual Climate Control to Automatic

Tags: ac, volvo

I own a Volvo s70 with the Manual Climate Control AC Control Unit. Is it possible to simply install an Automatic Climate Control Unit? Or does this require additional work? (Not just drag and drop kind of work?)

Comment: Not sure on your Volvo, but most automatic climate controls have a different type of resistor which controls the fan speed than does a manual one. I found this out on my pickup-truck when the resistor went bad in it. So, probably not a drop in. Would take a bit of work to make it happen, but not out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Parts for these older volvos are actually pretty cheap. And Dealer said ACC to MCC requires a new wire from the Climate Unit and that MCC is actually a better choice. Oh well.

Answer (score -2):

Changing from manual to auto control would involve changing a great many parts. The change would be very expensive, and parts availability for your year vehicle would be a nightmare.

Comment: Parts for these older volvos are actually pretty cheap. And Dealer said ACC to MCC requires a new wire from the Climate Unit and that MCC is actually a better choice. Oh well.

Comment: How much you want to do the job has an outlook on your perception of costs. If you want to do the job then the parts will look cheap. If you have to do the job, all of a sudden they will look expensive.